# Problems with mod_rewrite in Apache (with WAMP)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

The Idea: I want to make it that anything that comes after the domain name and ends with .html is treated as a get variable by index.php

Example: `www.test.ro/1/2/3.html` should actually be `www.test.ro/index.php?var=1/2/3.html`.

`www.test.ro` is setup as a virtual host for development, and `AllowOverride` has value All.

The .htaccess file seems to be processed, but not all the time. If I write a non-recognized rule like 'BizzareRule', the server works without returning a code 500 error.
If I put correct rules between `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>`, I get an 500 error, even though I have other vhosts using the same conditions and working perfectly.

Here are the contents of my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin eu@localhost.com
    ServerName  www.test.ro
    ServerAlias test.ro

    DocumentRoot D:/Projects/grabsite/test.ro
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog D:/Projects/grabsite/test.ro/error.log
    CustomLog D:/Projects/grabsite/test.ro/access.log combined

    <Directory "D:/Projects/grabsite/test.ro">
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And test content for .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?seo=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you enters in infinite loop. Try first to simplify the rule:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /index.php?seo=$1 [L]`

Or just
`RewriteRule ^index.html$ /index.php?seo=$1 [L]`

Next, it's best to have RewriteCond -f and RewriteCond -d in order not to execute the rule if you are requesting existing file/folder. In some situations, this can prevent an infinite loop in the rule

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in regex pattern. You said: *"The .htaccess file seems to be processed, but not all the time"*.

If you check your pattern`^/?([^/]*)\.html$` you will see that this will work for files **in root folder ONLY** (e.g. `/index.html`).

**Solution:** change pattern to `^(.+)\.html$` and all will be fine -- now it will match **ANY** URL that ends with **.html** (e.g. `/index.html` as well as `/hello/pink-kitten.html` etc).